# Can I create a template (non-type) param class that can take any enum? C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums, template-meta-programming

Here is a snippet of some example code that does recursion on templates.  I am trying to create an algorithm that takes any enum (from `0...n`, sequential) and performs an 'algorithm' based on those values using traits (does this recursively by subtracting the largest enum by 1).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum enum_type : size_t
{
    DEFAULT = 0,
    ONE = 1,
    TWO = 2,
    THREE = 3,
    FOUR = 4,
    MAX = FOUR,
};

template < enum_type F >
struct traits;

template < >
struct traits<ONE>
{
    static void do_something() {}
};

template < >
struct traits<TWO>
{
    static void do_something() {}
};

template < >
struct traits<THREE>
{
    static void do_something() {}
};

template < >
struct traits<FOUR>
{
    static void do_something() {}
};

template < enum_type F, typename TT = traits<F> >
struct attr_engine
{
    static void set()    {
        printf("Number: %lu ", F);

        TT::do_something();

        // get a compile error of trying to subtract an enum to an integer
        constexpr enum_type NEXT_FIELD = static_cast<enum_type>(F - 1);
        attr_engine<NEXT_FIELD>::set();
        return;
    }
};

template < >
struct attr_engine<DEFAULT, traits<DEFAULT>>
{
    static void set()    {
    printf("Reached the end");
    return;
    }
};

int main()
{
   attr_engine<MAX>::set();

   return 0;
}
```

I would like to create this into a "generic" algorithm that can take **any** enum (`enum_type2` instead of only `enum_type`, etc.) but I'm not quite sure how to to do this with non-type template params, or it is even possible.

I can't use typename because I'm using a non-type template param.

```
template < typename F, typename TT = traits<F> >
struct attr_engine
```

As an alternative, I've considered using a `std::size_t` potentially:

```
template < size_t F, typename TT = traits<F> >
struct attr_engine
```

But trying to create a generic `F` that can be deduced into its appropriate trait is something I'm stuck on.  I need some new approaches. I'm worried that doing that would cause me to cast the input non-template param which looks messy.

```
enum enum_type2
{
    DEFAULT_ENUM2,
    ONE_VAL,
    TWO_VAL,
    THREE_VAL,
    FOUR_VAL,
    ENUM2_MAX = FOUR_VAL,
};

int main()
{
   attr_engine<static_cast<sizet>(ENUM2_MAX)>::set();

   return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but I think SFINAE should be used... something like `typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<E>::value, E>::type`. Sorry I don't have the time to write a full answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create this into a "generic" algorithm that can take any enum (enum_type2 instead of only enum_type, etc.) but I'm not quite sure how to to do this with non-type template params, or it is even possible.

You tagged C++11, so you can't use `auto` as template type parameter (available starting from C++17), so you have to express, as template type parameter, the `enum` you're using.

The best I can imagine is the following

```
#include <iostream>

enum enum_type : std::size_t
 { DEFAULT = 0, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, MAX = FOUR, };

enum enum_type2 : std::size_t
 { DEFAULTbis = 0, ONEbis, TWObis, THREEbis, MAXbis = THREEbis, };

template <typename ET, ET F>
struct traits
 { static void do_something() {} };

template <typename ET, ET F, typename TT = traits<ET, F>, typename = void>
struct attr_engine
 {
   static void set ()
    {
      std::cout << "Number: " << F << std::endl;

      TT::do_something();

      constexpr ET NEXT_FIELD = static_cast<ET>(F - 1u);
      attr_engine<ET, NEXT_FIELD>::set();
    }
 };

template <typename ET, ET F>
struct attr_engine<ET, F, traits<ET, F>,
                   typename std::enable_if<0u == F>::type>
 { static void set() { std::cout << "Reached the end" << std::endl; } };

int main ()
 {
   attr_engine<decltype(MAX), MAX>::set();
   attr_engine<decltype(MAXbis), MAXbis>::set();
 }
```

If (when) you can use C++17, all become simpler

```
#include <iostream>

enum enum_type : std::size_t
 { DEFAULT = 0, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, MAX = FOUR, };

enum enum_type2 : std::size_t
 { DEFAULTbis = 0, ONEbis, TWObis, THREEbis, MAXbis = THREEbis, };

template <auto>
struct traits
 { static void do_something() {} };

template <auto F, typename TT = traits<F>, typename = void>
struct attr_engine
 {
   static void set ()
    {
      std::cout << "Number: " << F << std::endl;

      TT::do_something();

      attr_engine<static_cast<decltype(F)>(F - 1u)>::set();
    }
 };

template <auto F>
struct attr_engine<F, traits<F>, typename std::enable_if<0u == F>::type>
 { static void set() { std::cout << "Reached the end" << std::endl; } };

int main ()
 {
   attr_engine<MAX>::set();
   attr_engine<MAXbis>::set();
 }
```